# Adding jquery to vue js

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I am trying to convert [SB Admin 2 bootstrap](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2) template to VueJs, I am facing an issue with including jQuery, and error say in chrome console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at eval (sb-admin-2.min.js?1fbf:49)
```

This is how I included jQuery, main.js file

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

import jquery from "./assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js";
window.jQuery = window.$ = jquery;

import "./assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
import "./assets/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js";

import "./assets/js/sb-admin-2.min.js";
import "./assets/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js";

import "./assets/js/demo/chart-area-demo.js";
import "./assets/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

The problem that the jQuery defined in sb-admin-2.min.js is not seen as defined even though I added this in the main js.

Also I tried to use npm install --save jquery and did the above with reference the jquery installed but no luck!

```
import jquery from "jquery";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;
global.$ = global.jQuery = jquery;
```

Any ideas?! or maybe something wrong with sb-admin js file !!!, i check it but nothing wrong found.

Comment: I've got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but I solved it by creating a folder in the public directory called js and added all my template js files there. Then in the index.html, import them like this

```
  <script src="/js/jquery-modal-video.min.js"></script>
```

It should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when using Vue 3 and Fomantic-UI, which relies on jQuery. I was getting `window.jQuery is not a function`.

I was able to solve this by doing the following:

1. Create a new file called `jquery-global.js` with the following content:

   ```js
   import $ from 'jquery';
   window.$ = $;
   window.jQuery = $;
   ```
2. Import that file in `main.js`:

   ```
   import './jquery-global';
   ```

See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/592#issuecomment-205783255).

I was also able to get it working using [@rollup/plugin-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-inject) and adding the following to my `vite.config.ts`:

```js
plugins: [
  inject({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
  })
]
```

So that might also be something worth looking into.